# How to size the camera in Unity (2D Project)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm working on a 2D project in unity and I'm having trouble getting the camera to the exact size I need. I would like the camera to be centered around a level I've already created, so I know exactly how tall and wide it should be, and where it should be centered. Where I get lost is translating these values to the properties of the camera. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put more details about your problem.

Unity's camera rect is resolution depend. So you cannot set width and height of camera size. For example if you have resolution 16:10, camera rect will have that ratio, you can only change scale of that real resolution.